# Text Replacement using app script for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Issue**

I am having some problems with text replacement using app script. I would like to get the desired output below but am currently having a few issues with additional commas and a lack of apostrophes.

**Code**

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow();
  var input_data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, row_count, 15).getValues();
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {

      var row_data; 

        // Table Row
      if (input_data[i][0] == "table") {
        row_data = "INSERT INTO " + input_data[i][1];

        // Fields Row
      } else if (input_data[i][0] == "fields") {
        row_data = "(" + input_data[i] + ")";

        // Values Row
      } else if (input_data[i][0] == "values") {
        row_data = "VALUES";

        // Entry Row
      } else if (input_data[i][0] == "entry") {
        row_data = "(" + input_data[i] + ");";

        // Empty Row
      } else if (input_data[i][0] == "") {
        row_data = "";
      }

      data.push([row_data]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 16, data.length, 1).setValues(data);
}
```

**Data**

[image]

**Current Output**

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
row_data = "(" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join(", ") + ")";
```

Or

```
row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '") + "')";
```

Comment: How do I ignore column a in the results?

Comment: I'm also getting the "Greenwich meantime" come up in the response which I do not want.

Comment: @Tris Look into array.shift() and str.split()

Comment: The two lines below did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help. 

```row_data = input_data[i].shift();
row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '").replace(" GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)", "") + "')";```

Comment: I have come across a new one where if I have multiple entries in one row only the first value is replaced with the replace.... Are you able to help with this?

```row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '").replace("'NULL'", "NULL") + "'),";```

Comment: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) if you need.

Comment: Appreciate the push into working it on my own... I can get it to work but cant replace with apostrophe ```var regex = /\'NULL\'/;
        row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '").replace(regex, "BLAH") + "'),";```

Comment: @Tris Quotes shouldn't matter. It's true that you should use regex, but you're missing something in the regex. In the link above, try in the JavaScript demo and "Run"

Comment: I tired the /gi but still wouldn't work with quotes.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong other than `/gi`. It's better if you ask a new question with [mcve]/sample data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173693/google-app-script-regex-replace-for-multiple-values-not-working-with-single-quot