# Google App Script regex replace for multiple values not working with single quote

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Problem**

Using the below code i'd like to replace all "'NULL'" values to "NULL". Currently it will only replace one value.

**Code**

```
function generateSQLCode() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('seed-data');
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow();
  var input_data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, row_count, 20).getValues();
  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {

      var row_data; 

      } else if (input_data[i][0] == "entry") {
        row_data = input_data[i].shift();
        row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '").replace(/'NULL'/gi, "NULL") + "');";


      data.push([row_data]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 21, data.length, 1).setValues(data);
}
```

**Data**

```
previous_version_id   dev_id    build_number                                            
NULL                  1         NULL
```

Comment: 1.Use proper tags. 2.Could you show exact data? If this: `NULL                  1         NULL` is a row, then join would produce `NULL', '1', 'NULL`. Note that no NULL is quoted on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out I resolved with ```} else if (input_data[i][0] == "entry") {
        row_data = input_data[i].shift();
        row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '") + "'),";
        row_data = row_data.replace(/'NULL'/gi, "NULL")```

Answer (score 0):

Had to reassign row_data to get the full string before replacing any NULL values.

```
else if (input_data[i][0] == "entry") {
row_data = input_data[i].shift();
row_data = "('" + input_data[i].filter(e=> e!=="").join("', '") + "'),";
row_data = row_data.replace(/'NULL'/gi, "NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of itereating for all the array that could be very time consuming let me recommend you a nice class built in Apps script called [`TxtFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder).

That could simplify a lot of your code and make it faster.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();


  var txtFinder = range.createTextFinder("'NULL'");
  txtFinder.replaceAllWith("NULL")


}
```

Try using this snippet and see how it goes.

#### Explanation

To use the `TxtFinder` class you first need to create an object, you can do with the method `createTextFinder`.

You can actually use this method not only for a range, like I did but [for the sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext) or even [the whole spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createtextfinderfindtext).

After having this object created (`txtFinder` in my example). You can do a lot of stuff listed in the [`TxtFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class. For your case just use [`replaceAllWith()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceAllWith(String)), to replace all the matches.

---

Also notice that if you want to look for all the data in your sheet, you can simply call [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)